# Error: cannot find module './lib/middleware'

Tags: node.js

I am attempting to run the demo for the [mobwrite node.js package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mobwrite). First I installed the mobwrite package (`npm install mobwrite`) and then entered the following command:

```
node -e "require('mobwrite').quickserve()"
```

A demo server should start, but the following error is thrown:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './lib/middleware'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:388:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (PATH_TO_MODULES\mobwrite.js:2:18)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at [eval]:1:1
  at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
  at Module._compie (module.js:456:26)
  at evalScript (node.js:532:25)
  at startup (node.js:80:7)
  at node.js:901:3
```

This originates from the mobwrite.js file, in which the package needs to include a middleware file (`middleware.coffee`) which is stored in a lib folder:

```
require("coffee-script")
middleware = require("./lib/middleware")
module.exports = middleware
```

I have looked at the answers to similar posts on SO, but nothing has solved my problem so far. How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try manually compiling the coffeescript files to javascript: `npm install -g coffee-script && coffee -c node_modules/mobwrite/lib/middleware.coffee && coffee -c node_modules/mobwrite/lib/daemon.coffee`. Then retry your command.

Comment: Thanks, I can now run the examples. Future users should note that this works fine for middleware.coffee, but for daemon.coffee you first need to remove the keyword `own` from line 177 (so it reads `for key in argumentKeyOrdering`).